# Get custom data from fcm in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with xamarin ios and firebase cloud messaging.

This is my fcm request body.

```
{
  "registration_ids": ["token1","token2"],
  "notification": {
    "sound": "default",
    "body": "test body",
    "title": "test with notification",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high"
  },
  "data": {
    "notificationType" : "notification"
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve "notificationType" in DidReceiveRemoteNotification method.

This is my method :

```
        [Export("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")]
        [ObjCRuntime.Introduced(ObjCRuntime.PlatformName.TvOS, 10, 0, ObjCRuntime.PlatformArchitecture.All, null)]
        [ObjCRuntime.Introduced(ObjCRuntime.PlatformName.iOS, 7, 0, ObjCRuntime.PlatformArchitecture.All, null)]
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

            NSDictionary data = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("data")) as NSDictionary;
            string notificationType = Convert.ToString(data[new NSString("notificationType")] as NSString);
        }
```

Let me know what I need to change here?
Thanks.